# What are the implications of large (20K) max_input_vars?

Tags: php, wordpress

On WordPress site, I have a plugin (export) that requires max_input_vars of 20K.

What are the implications of such (rare) huge size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237409/what-does-max-input-vars-in-php-ini-actually-affect-and-what-is-a-safe-high-valu may give some more info.